ERR_TUNNEL_CONNNECTION_FAILED while using Proxy Server with Selenium in Python
Just trying to implement the basic code for using a proxy server with selenium. Have tried several free proxies and they all cause google to return "ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED." Could be that free proxy servers are not reliable, but I could have also made a mistake in my code below:
import seleniumwire
from seleniumwire import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')

sw_options = {
    'proxy': {
    '    https': 'https://162.245.85.220:80'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=chrome_options,
    seleniumwire_options=sw_options,
)

driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/")

Any help would be appreciated.
Was expecting for Selenium to return the IP address of the free proxy server.

If that's literally your code, remove the spaces from '   https'.

remove the space from https and also try with http

Also can you try below and check what response code does it give currently try:
response = requests.get('https://whatismyipaddress.com/', proxies=proxy)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
print(f"Proxy test failed: {e}")
